# Downloading .json file in react native

Tags: react-native

I have been hitting a wall trying to download a `.json` file into the local Downloads folder of my ios and android device.

In my app users are able to download their `json` data and transfer it to another device. It is basically a backup feature. I have `react-native-fs` installed and have used it before. But I don't know how to download the json data.

I tried this with no success:

```
const uploadPayload = JSON.stringify(appStateToUpload)

const dirPath = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}/Moodflow`

await RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(dirPath)

const filePath = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}/Moodflow/${BACKUP_FILE_NAME}_${moment().format('D_M_YYYY__HH_mm')}.json`

return RNFetchBlob.fs.appendFile(filePath, uploadPayload, 'utf8').then(() => ...)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using `react-native-fs` you can do this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const data = {
  name: 'My name',
  age: '20',
};

const path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.json';

const App = () => {
  const handlePress = async () => {
    try {
      await RNFS.writeFile(path, data, 'utf8');
      console.log('Success!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
        <Text>Press Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The list of directories can be found [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#API)

However, you will have no feedback that the file was created. It would be interesting to show a notification that redirects the user to the directory.

Comment: I already tried that before and did not work. `.appendFile` functions very similarly  to `.writeFile`

Comment: The issue was that you need to ask for permission first with `PermissionsAndroid`