# generate CSV file from json object on button clicked in react native

Tags: react-native, export-to-csv

I am building and `mobile app` for android using react native, I have json array object and I want to download this data as `CSV` file on button clicked, I have checked many of existing packages but all for **web applications not mobile applications**. is there anyway or trick to do that or is there and new packages i am missing. help me please

Comment: npm install rn-fetch-blob

Comment: @Ki-HyounKim based on what i read that rn-fetch-blob is only for geting files from fetch api or upload them. but for me my data is in frontend of the app

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, this is for a different use case. But maybe try to fit this for your application: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489640/downloading-json-file-in-react-native and here is the official documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs/v/1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like react-native-fs ([https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs](https://npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs)) supports IOS and Android Devices. This allows you to create Files on the Device, and write any File content.